# NO_POSE -- NOT_OBSERVED error in Vuforia v10.17.4

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Recently, I upgraded Vuforia from 10.16.5 to 10.17.4 and before, I was using unity 2022.1.17f1 but the latest Vuforia version is not supported for Unity 2022.1.17f1 so I upgraded my Unity version to 2022.3.9f1.

Now when i hit play button in Unity, it throws a comment like below, and all my models disappear from Unity, and in simulation, a black screen appears.
[IMAGE FOR REFERENCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I955D.png)

Please help me out.

Target status: BUTTERFLY NO_POSE -- NOT_OBSERVED
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
DefaultObserverEventHandler:OnObserverStatusChanged (Vuforia.ObserverBehaviour,Vuforia.TargetStatus) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@27bfa56ccb82/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultObserverEventHandler.cs:92)
DefaultObserverEventHandler:Start () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@27bfa56ccb82/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultObserverEventHandler.cs:61)

Here is the code :

```
/*==============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2021 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Confidential and Proprietary - Protected under copyright and other laws.
Vuforia is a trademark of PTC Inc., registered in the United States and other 
countries.
==============================================================================*/

using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Vuforia;

/// <summary>
/// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
///
/// Changes made to this file could be overwritten when upgrading the Vuforia version.
/// When implementing custom event handler behavior, consider inheriting from this class instead.
/// </summary>
public class DefaultObserverEventHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TrackingStatusFilter
    {
        Tracked,
        Tracked_ExtendedTracked,
        Tracked_ExtendedTracked_Limited
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A filter that can be set to either:
    /// - Only consider a target if it's in view (TRACKED)
    /// - Also consider the target if's outside of the view, but the environment is tracked (EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    /// - Even consider the target if tracking is in LIMITED mode, e.g. the environment is just 3dof tracked.
    /// </summary>
    public TrackingStatusFilter StatusFilter = TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked_Limited;

    public bool UsePoseSmoothing = false;
    public AnimationCurve AnimationCurve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, 0, LERP_DURATION, 1);
    
    public UnityEvent OnTargetFound;
    public UnityEvent OnTargetLost;


    protected ObserverBehaviour mObserverBehaviour;
    protected TargetStatus mPreviousTargetStatus = TargetStatus.NotObserved;
    protected bool mCallbackReceivedOnce;
    
    const float LERP_DURATION = 0.3f;

    PoseSmoother mPoseSmoother;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        mObserverBehaviour = GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();
        
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnObserverStatusChanged;
            mObserverBehaviour.OnBehaviourDestroyed += OnObserverDestroyed;

            OnObserverStatusChanged(mObserverBehaviour, mObserverBehaviour.TargetStatus);
            SetupPoseSmoothing();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(VuforiaBehaviour.Instance != null)
            VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.World.OnStateUpdated -= OnStateUpdated;
        
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
            OnObserverDestroyed(mObserverBehaviour);
        
        mPoseSmoother?.Dispose();
    }

    void OnObserverDestroyed(ObserverBehaviour observer)
    {
        mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged -= OnObserverStatusChanged;
        mObserverBehaviour.OnBehaviourDestroyed -= OnObserverDestroyed;
        mObserverBehaviour = null;
    }

    void OnObserverStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour behaviour, TargetStatus targetStatus)
    {
        var name = mObserverBehaviour.TargetName;
        if (mObserverBehaviour is VuMarkBehaviour vuMarkBehaviour && vuMarkBehaviour.InstanceId != null)
        {
            name += " (" + vuMarkBehaviour.InstanceId + ")";
        }

        Debug.Log($"Target status: {name} {targetStatus.Status} -- {targetStatus.StatusInfo}");

        HandleTargetStatusChanged(mPreviousTargetStatus.Status, targetStatus.Status);
        HandleTargetStatusInfoChanged(targetStatus.StatusInfo);
        
        mPreviousTargetStatus = targetStatus;
    }

    protected virtual void HandleTargetStatusChanged(Status previousStatus, Status newStatus)
    {
        var shouldBeRendererBefore = ShouldBeRendered(previousStatus);
        var shouldBeRendererNow = ShouldBeRendered(newStatus);
        if (shouldBeRendererBefore != shouldBeRendererNow)
        {
            if (shouldBeRendererNow)
            {
                OnTrackingFound();
            }
            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!mCallbackReceivedOnce && !shouldBeRendererNow)
            {
                // This is the first time we are receiving this callback, and the target is not visible yet.
                // --> Hide the augmentation.
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }

        mCallbackReceivedOnce = true;
    }

    protected virtual void HandleTargetStatusInfoChanged(StatusInfo newStatusInfo)
    {
        if (newStatusInfo == StatusInfo.WRONG_SCALE)
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat("The target {0} appears to be scaled incorrectly. " +
                                 "This might result in tracking issues. " +
                                 "Please make sure that the target size corresponds to the size of the " +
                                 "physical object in meters and regenerate the target or set the correct " +
                                 "size in the target's inspector.", mObserverBehaviour.TargetName);
        }
    }

    protected bool ShouldBeRendered(Status status)
    {
        if (status == Status.TRACKED)
        {
            // always render the augmentation when status is TRACKED, regardless of filter
            return true;
        }

        if (StatusFilter == TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked && status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            // also return true if the target is extended tracked
            return true;
        }

        if (StatusFilter == TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked_ExtendedTracked_Limited &&
            (status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED || status == Status.LIMITED))
        {
            // in this mode, render the augmentation even if the target's tracking status is LIMITED.
            // this is mainly recommended for Anchors.
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            var rendererComponents = mObserverBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            var colliderComponents = mObserverBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            var canvasComponents = mObserverBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

            // Enable rendering:
            foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
                component.enabled = true;

            // Enable colliders:
            foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
                component.enabled = true;

            // Enable canvas':
            foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
                component.enabled = true;
        }

        OnTargetFound?.Invoke();
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            var rendererComponents = mObserverBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            var colliderComponents = mObserverBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            var canvasComponents = mObserverBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

            // Disable rendering:
            foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
                component.enabled = false;

            // Disable colliders:
            foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
                component.enabled = false;

            // Disable canvas':
            foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
                component.enabled = false;
        }

        OnTargetLost?.Invoke();
    }

    protected void SetupPoseSmoothing()
    {
        UsePoseSmoothing &= VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.WorldCenterMode == WorldCenterMode.DEVICE; // pose smoothing only works with the DEVICE world center mode
        mPoseSmoother = new PoseSmoother(mObserverBehaviour, AnimationCurve);
        
        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.World.OnStateUpdated += OnStateUpdated;
    }

    void OnStateUpdated()
    {
        if (enabled && UsePoseSmoothing)
            mPoseSmoother.Update();
    }

    class PoseSmoother
    {
        const float e = 0.001f;
        const float MIN_ANGLE = 2f;

        PoseLerp mActivePoseLerp;
        Pose mPreviousPose;
        
        readonly ObserverBehaviour mTarget;
        readonly AnimationCurve mAnimationCurve;
        
        TargetStatus mPreviousStatus;

        public PoseSmoother(ObserverBehaviour target, AnimationCurve animationCurve)
        {
            mTarget = target;
            mAnimationCurve = animationCurve;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            var currentPose = new Pose(mTarget.transform.position, mTarget.transform.rotation);
            var currentStatus = mTarget.TargetStatus;

            UpdatePoseSmoothing(currentPose, currentStatus);

            mPreviousPose = currentPose;
            mPreviousStatus = currentStatus;
        }
        
        void UpdatePoseSmoothing(Pose currentPose, TargetStatus currentTargetStatus)
        {
            if (mActivePoseLerp == null && ShouldSmooth(currentPose, currentTargetStatus))
            {
                mActivePoseLerp = new PoseLerp(mPreviousPose, currentPose, mAnimationCurve);
            }
        
            if (mActivePoseLerp != null)
            {
                var pose = mActivePoseLerp.GetSmoothedPosition(Time.deltaTime);
                mTarget.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(pose.position, pose.rotation);

                if (mActivePoseLerp.Complete)
                {
                    mActivePoseLerp = null;
                }
            }
        }
        
        /// Smooth pose transition if the pose changed and the target is still being reported as "extended tracked" or it has just returned to
        /// "tracked" from previously being "extended tracked"
        bool ShouldSmooth(Pose currentPose, TargetStatus currentTargetStatus)
        {
            return (currentTargetStatus.Status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED || (currentTargetStatus.Status == Status.TRACKED && mPreviousStatus.Status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)) &&
                   (Vector3.SqrMagnitude(currentPose.position - mPreviousPose.position) > e || Quaternion.Angle(currentPose.rotation, mPreviousPose.rotation) > MIN_ANGLE);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            mActivePoseLerp = null;
        }
    }

    class PoseLerp
    {
        readonly AnimationCurve mCurve;
        readonly Pose mStartPose;
        readonly Pose mEndPose;
        readonly float mEndTime;

        float mElapsedTime;

        public bool Complete { get; private set; }

        public PoseLerp(Pose startPose, Pose endPose, AnimationCurve curve)
        {
            mStartPose = startPose;
            mEndPose = endPose;
            mCurve = curve;
            mEndTime = mCurve.keys[mCurve.length - 1].time;
        }

        public Pose GetSmoothedPosition(float deltaTime)
        {
            mElapsedTime += deltaTime;

            if (mElapsedTime >= mEndTime)
            {
                mElapsedTime = 0;
                Complete = true;
                return mEndPose;
            }

            var ratio = mCurve.Evaluate(mElapsedTime);
            var smoothPosition = Vector3.Lerp(mStartPose.position, mEndPose.position, ratio);
            var smoothRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(mStartPose.rotation, mEndPose.rotation, ratio);

            return new Pose(smoothPosition, smoothRotation);
        }
    }
}
```

previous verssion of vuforia and unity were working fine but now vuforia dont provide old version of sdk so iam stuck with the new version

Comment: Issue is solved I used older v10.10.2 sdk and used DefaultObserverEventHandler.cs script of v10.10.2 and finally all the error solved.